# I am not able to see other person video when someone joins server

Tags: node.js, video, stream, webrtc, peer

I have tried to create zoom clone using nodejs i have successfully displayed my video in the web page and created id for each person joining the link but while it is not dispalying joined person video

I'm use peerjs library to call the user and display him in the web page

client.js

```
    const socket = io('/')
    const videoGrid =  document.getElementById('video-grid')
    const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
    myVideo.muted = true;

    var peer = new Peer(undefined,{
        path : "/peerjs",
        host : '/', // host either be heroku or whatever
        port : '3030'
    })

      peer.on('open',id => {
        socket.emit('join-room',RoomID,id)
    })

    let myVideoStream 
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video : true,
        audio: false
    }).then(stream => {
        myVideoStream = stream; 
        console.log('my video')
        addOurVideoStream(myVideo,stream);

    
        
        peer.on('call', call => {
            const video = document.createElement('video')      
            console.log('working')  
            call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
            call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
                console.log('succesfully answer')
                addUserVideoStream(video,userVideoStream)  
            });
        
        });

     socket.on('user-connected',(userId)=> {
            console.log(userId)
            connectToNewUser(userId,stream);
        })
    
    });

     const connectToNewUser = (userId,stream) => {
        console.log('connect to new user')
        const call = peer.call(userId,stream);
        console.log('sucess')
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
            console.log('succesfully call')
            addUserVideoStream(video,userVideoStream)
        })

        call.on('close', () => {
            video.remove()
        })

    } 

    const addOurVideoStream = (video,stream) => {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', ()=> {
            video.play();
        })

    videoGrid.append(video)
    }

    const addUserVideoStream = (video,stream) => {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
            video.play()
        })
        videoGrid.append(video)
    }
```

app.js in server

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const { v4: uuidv4 }  =  require('uuid') ;
    const server = require('http').Server(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server)
    const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
    const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server,{
       debug: true
    });

    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use('/peerjs',peerServer)

    app.get('/',(req,res,next) => {
       res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`)
    })

    app.get('/:room', (req,res,next) => {
       const roomId = req.params.room
       res.render('room' , {
       roomId : roomId
        })  
      // console.log(roomId)
    })

    io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join-room',(roomID,userId) => {
    socket.join(roomID)
    socket.to(roomID).broadcast.emit('user-connected',userId)
})

   socket.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
   })
})

   server.listen(3030,() => {
       console.log('connected')
   })
```

room.ejs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script>
    const RoomID =  "<%= roomId  %> "
</script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
<title>Zoom Clone</title>

 </head>
   <body>
     <div id="video-grid">
     </div>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try and replace
socket.on('user-connected',(userId)=> {
console.log(userId)
      connectToNewUser(userId,stream);
        })
with 
socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
      // user is joining`
    setTimeout(() => {
        // user joined
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
      }, 1000)
    })
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two code pieces missing in client.js file!

```
var getUserMedia = 
navigator.getUserMedia || 
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || 
navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

You should add this code just below the Peer object creation as shown below:(I am not sure why we are adding this, but untill I added this code piece, my code was not working.)

```
const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
host:"/",
port:"3030",
path:"/peerjs"
})

var getUserMedia =
navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

Also, you have to make method to recieve calls
Till now, you have created method to display your video to you only. To create a method which will show the other person's video on screen, add the code given below:

```
peer.on("call", function(call){
getUserMedia({
      video:true,
      audio:true

  }, function(stream){
    call.answer(stream);
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    call.on("stream", function (remoteStream) {
      addVideoStream(video, remoteStream);
    });
  }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
  })
})
```

I hope it would work now!
Thank You!

Comment: It works perfectly with web to web but I couldn't see the video from mobile ?